# Context-free Grammar for L={a^xb^yc^x+y where x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0}

Tags: automata, automata-theory

Im really having trouble wrapping my head on this one.

but I know that this could be written like:

**a^x b^y c^x c^y**

advance thank you for the help

Comment: You'll get farther from thinking about it as `a^x b^y c^y c^x` instead. Consider how you would solve `b^y c^y` and `a^x q c^x`, then replace `q` with `b^y c^y`'s solution.

Comment: Oh my that makes a lot of sense. I was getting stuck at thinking it should be c^x c^y. Lol thank you so much